# How to get list of USA states from Wikidata by API?

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

I tried to find the states of USA with Wikidata API but there is no results.

For example: http://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[150:30]

- P150 - [contains administrative territorial entity](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P150)
- Q30 - [United States of America](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q30)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need all Wikidata items which have P31 with value Q35657: [claim[31:35657]](https://wdq.wmflabs.org/api?q=claim[31:35657])

- P31 - [instance of](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31)
- Q35657 - [state of the United States](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q35657)

Answer (score 0):

With SPARQL, you can do that

```
SELECT ?state ?stateLabel
WHERE { 
   ?state wdt:P31 wd:Q35657.
   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fstate%20%3FstateLabel%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%3Fstate%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ35657.%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)